# Ignore characters with regex in cucumber step definition

Tags: javascript, regex, cucumber

I'm trying to capture the digits inside a value using regex whilst ignoring the characters.

Feature Step: **Then the '1st' 'elementName' repeating group is displayed on the 'webPage' page**

I want to take the **'1'** from the '1st' value and ignore the characters left in the string. As I have no use for the characters in what I'm trying to achieve.

Current Step Def:

`Then(/the 'areaINeedHelp' '([^"]*)' repeating group is displayed on the '([^"]*)' page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a back reference that captures the number, but omits the number suffix:

```
Then(/the '(\d+).{2}' '([^']*)' repeating group is displayed on the '([^']*)' page/
```

Also change `[^"]*` to `[^']*` in the other two back references, since you are using single quotes around the step arguments instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been trying this for too long hah. Out of interest why do you suggest changing the [^"]*  to [^']* as this is working for me no problem currently.

Comment: Because `[^"]*` means **any non-double quote character zero or more times, and your regular expression was denoting arguments with single quotes. It only worked by coincidence. If you had specified a page name that contained a double quote then the regex would not have matched the full page name.